# How to select items whose expiry date match with the current date and find the difference between them

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a table `ProductsTable` with the following columns:

```
ProductID, ProductName, ExpiryDate
```

Now I want to select those products from the table whose expiry date is less than 90 days using a query. I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Can anyone give me a guide?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you already look at the DATEDIFF function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @KlausGütter your link is in German, in case you haven't noticed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductsTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,ExpiryDate,GETDATE()) < 90
```